# HyperLink control produces System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, object, instance

I know that this is a dead horse that's been beaten over and over again but I need some assistance resolving a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." problem. I've gone to numerous links but I am new to programming I can't make heads from tails for these suggestions.

The error occurs on line 47:

```
Line 45: HyperLink topNavigation = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLinkTopNavigation");
Line 46: //Use Sitecore API to get the link to the Item and upadte the href property of link
Line 47: topNavigation.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(currentItem);
Line 48: //Assign name to the link
Line 49: topNavigation.Text = currentItem.Name;
```

---

My ascx code is:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"  Inherits="Layouts.Topnavigation.TopnavigationSublayout" CodeFile="~/layouts/TopNavigation.ascx.cs"  Debug="true" %>

<%@ register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>
    <asp:repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterTopNavigation" onitemdatabound="RepeaterTopNavigation_ItemDataBound">
<headertemplate>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>


<itemtemplate>
<li>
<asp:hyperlink id="HyperLinkTopNavigation" runat="server"></asp:hyperlink>
</li>
</itemtemplate>

<footertemplate>

</footertemplate></ul></headertemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

My behind code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Links;


namespace Layouts.Topnavigation {

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TopnavigationSublayout
    /// </summary>
  public partial class TopnavigationSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
{
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//get the home item, this is hardcoded but you can define it in web.config
Item home = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
//get all children from home using Sitecore API
Item[] children = home.Children.ToArray();
//Bind the children to repeater
RepeaterTopNavigation.DataSource = children;
RepeaterTopNavigation.DataBind();

}

public void RepeaterTopNavigation_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
//gets the current data item from RepeaterItemEventsArgs and cast it as a Sitecore Item
Item currentItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;

//check if it is not null, safety first
if (currentItem != null)
{

//check if it is coming from Item or Alternating Item template
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
          e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{

//Find the HyperLink control that has been defined in repeater
HyperLink topNavigation = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLinkTopNavigation");
//Use Sitecore API to get the link to the Item and upadte the href property of link
topNavigation.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(currentItem);
//Assign name to the link
topNavigation.Text = currentItem.Name;

}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's gotta be either `topNavigation` or `currentItem`.  You're checking for currentItem being null, so I believe something is going on with `topNavigation`...

Comment: You may need to do a recursive FindControl search for HyperLinkTopNavigation - either that or it's not loaded yet when that event fires.

Comment: Are you sure that currentItem has a `Name` property?

Answer (score 0):

Your `headertemplate` tag is wrapping the entire repeater, which is probably why the HyperLink control isn't being found. Fix it like this:

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterTopNavigation" onitemdatabound="RepeaterTopNavigation_ItemDataBound">
<headertemplate>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
<li>
<asp:hyperlink id="HyperLinkTopNavigation" runat="server"></asp:hyperlink>
</li>
</itemtemplate>

<footertemplate>
</ul>
</footertemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```